# Access Bound Combobox with lookup Field?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a table.  Table1.  Table1.[Field1] displays a lookup field taken from Table2.[Field2].

In my Form I have two comboboxes.  Combobox1 is bound to Table1.[Field2].

Remember.... Table1.[Field1] is displaying the "looked up value".

What I want to do is to use a bound Combobox2 so that it displays the looked up value (I have achieved this)... and then, when I change that value using the drop down list in Combobox2 to another value, it changes the record displayed in all my other controls, including Combobox1.

I'm not too sure what settings to use in my properties.  Would anyone know how to achieve the above?

Thanks
(MS Access 2010)(Windows 7 Pro)

Comment: have you checked 'recordsource' in the properties pane?

Comment: I can't see anything which says recordsource.  I can only see Row Source. However, in row source my lookup combobox displays values from Table2 so I'm not sure if it's showing any relationship to Table1 which is the table I want to change the records in.

Comment: On second thoughts, it's definitely right.  When I change the record via the arrows at the bottom of the form they change the records in both comboboxes simultaneusly which is what I want.  I just can't make a change in the combobox value reflect in all the other comboboxes.  Maybe that's what I should be asking.